# Sign jars with gradle and yubikey

Tags: gradle, gnupg, sign, yubico

I am trying to sign my jars with yubikey and gradle.

For gradle I am using the signing plugin. Unfortunately I don't get it working with setting it up in the usual way since you have to provide the secring.gpg which should contain the private key as far as I got. Since the key resides on the yubikey, this is not going to work.

Probably there are some android devs around using yubikeys and signing their jars?

I'd appreciate any help!

Sign task:

```
signing {
    required { gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("uploadArchives") }
    sign configurations.archives
}
```

Gradle.properties:

```
signing.keyId= 1234ABCD
signing.password=secret
signing.secretKeyRingFile=/home/user/.gnupg/secring.gpg
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not evaluate onlyIf predicate for task ':signArchives'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:230)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$RunTasksAction.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:227)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:95)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:66)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: Exception constructing key
        at org.gradle.plugins.signing.signatory.pgp.PgpSignatory.createPrivateKey(PgpSignatory.java:118)
        at org.gradle.plugins.signing.signatory.pgp.PgpSignatory.<init>(PgpSignatory.java:55)
        at org.gradle.plugins.signing.signatory.pgp.PgpSignatoryFactory.createSignatory(PgpSignatoryFactory.java:72)
        at org.gradle.plugins.signing.signatory.pgp.PgpSignatoryFactory.createSignatory(PgpSignatoryFactory.java:68)
        at org.gradle.plugins.signing.signatory.pgp.PgpSignatoryFactory.readProperties(PgpSignatoryFactory.java:98)
        at org.gradle.plugins.signing.signatory.pgp.PgpSignatoryFactory.createSignatory(PgpSignatoryFactory.java:44)
        at org.gradle.plugins.signing.signatory.pgp.PgpSignatoryFactory.createSignatory(PgpSignatoryFactory.java:48)
        at org.gradle.plugins.signing.signatory.pgp.PgpSignatoryProvider.getDefaultSignatory(PgpSignatoryProvider.java:41)
        at org.gradle.plugins.signing.signatory.pgp.PgpSignatoryProvider.getDefaultSignatory(PgpSignatoryProvider.java:30)
        at org.gradle.plugins.signing.SigningExtension.getSignatory(SigningExtension.java:180)
        at org.gradle.plugins.signing.SigningExtension_Decorated.getSignatory(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.plugins.signing.SigningExtension$2.call(SigningExtension.java:226)
        at org.gradle.plugins.signing.SigningExtension$2.call(SigningExtension.java:224)
        at org.gradle.util.GUtil.uncheckedCall(GUtil.java:402)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper$2.getValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper$MappedPropertyImpl.getValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:133)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper.getConventionValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:111)
        at org.gradle.plugins.signing.Sign_Decorated.getSignatory(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.plugins.signing.Sign$3.isSatisfiedBy(Sign.java:94)
        at org.gradle.plugins.signing.Sign$3.isSatisfiedBy(Sign.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.specs.AndSpec.isSatisfiedBy(AndSpec.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:42)
        ... 63 more
Caused by: org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: Exception constructing key
        at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKey.extractPrivateKey(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.plugins.signing.signatory.pgp.PgpSignatory.createPrivateKey(PgpSignatory.java:116)
        ... 84 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.BCPGInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.MPInteger.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.RSASecretBCPGKey.<init>(Unknown Source)
        ... 86 more
```

Best

Comment: Can you share relevant parts of your `build.gradle`, `gradle.properties`, and the error you get?

Comment: Actually this seems to be an issue of gradle. I migrated everything to Maven now, and it's working out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I sign jars with Gradle and YubiKey with no problem. In my `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file, I have:

```
signing.gnupg.executable=gpg
signing.gnupg.homeDir=/home/raman/.gnupg
signing.gnupg.optionsFile=/home/raman/.gnupg/gpg.conf
signing.gnupg.keyName=1F3CE06C51CE20F7C4405181943F287533382C9D
```

The `keyName` is the value reported by `gpg --list-secret-keys`. Look for the "sec" (secret) key that shows as being present on the YubiKey (the output should show "Card serial no. = ...". The hex value just above the card serial number is the `keyName`. Example:

```
...<snip>...
sec>  rsa4096/943F287533382C9D 2022-04-23 [SC] [expires: 2024-04-22]
1F3CE06C51CE20F7C4405181943F287533382C9D  <--- this value here
Card serial no. = 0006 19052983
...<snip>...
```